# Choosing which of the independent variables to enter into multinomial regression

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, regression-strategies

I am  performing regression analysis only very newly, so am practically lacking skills! It would be greatly appreciated getting your guidance pls.

I have 50 observations of 26 IV (categorical ) and One nominal(or ordinal?) DV (detected above average, detected below average, not detected). I am interested in knowing which  of those IV contributed mostly to status of DV. SO i ran multinomial regression. In order to decide which of the 26 IV i should enter, I initially performed a separate linear regression analysis to test the significant explanatory variables to an overall assessment score (DV)- which is a total score on all 26 IV for each observation. So i considered those variables as the most meaningful to enter. is it a wrong approach?

- and how wrong would be the other approach to perform factorial analysis and enter those variables in a factor with high eigen value? note: i have limited understanding of this test, but somehow when i did it, i ended up with a factor of 17 components explaining 95% of variations

I appreciate a lot your help , although i may have sounded not reasonable with my method!

Comment: With which statistical packages are you familiar?

Comment: I am familiar with Chi-Square, and other non-parametric tests. Besides, multivariate analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disasters caused by stepwise regression have been written about extensively on this site.  And your ordinal DV may be defective as it did not preserve all the information in the underlying measurement, which results in significant power and precision loss.  With such an ordinal variable with only 3 categories, especially if one of the categories has a low frequency, you have very limited information.  The question is not whether you can let the data tell you what to do (it can't) you have the bigger issue of whether you have an adequate sample size even if there are **no** predictors.  For a binary DV the minimum sample size needed just to estimate the intercept in the model is 96 observations.

Comment: Thank  you Frank. this was a very helpful answer, although worrying re.limitation for use.

Comment: Dr Frank thank you! what would you suggest for an alternative test please? only association test like Somer'd or correlation? I understand i cant use regression analysis with this sample size (n=50)

Comment: It is not the statistical approach that is the problem it is (1) the sample size and (2) the use of an almost minimum information DV.  The only way to have a higher effective sample size when the real sample size is 50 is to have a high-information high-precision DV - either a continuous variable or an ordinal one with many well-populated levels.

Comment: got the point. Many thanks for the feedback! that was of great help before i use a wrong approach.